# Animating a sequence of .png images (no other questions helped)

Tags: animate

I want to animate a series of images in my document, but I get the following error:

`! Package animate Error: None of the files(animate) Monkey-0.pdf',(animate)...`

and this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   \animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{1}{Monkey-}{0}{59}
\end{document}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong since the files are in the folder and I'm not adding the extension inside the command. (I'm using TexMaker)

Comment: What happens if you replace `\animategraphics...` with `\includegraphics{Monkey-0}`? Make sure the real filename is spelled exactly as in the inclusion command and the extension is lower case. Filenames in TeX are case sensitive.

Comment: Tried it and the image shows up. That's why I don't get why the animation isn't working!

Comment: `Monkey-0.png` or `Monkey-0.PNG`? `\animategraphics` wants the former.

Comment: Your code works fine with `Monkey-0.pdf`, `Monkey-1.pdf`, `Monkey-2.pdf` (files). Tested with `\animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{1}{Monkey-}{0}{2}`. So i can't reproduce your error. Have you checked the file extension?